# How to convert php hierarchical array in nested sets?

Tags: php, nested-sets

I have a hierarchical array.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 28
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 29
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 30
            [children] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 31
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

I need to get keys «left», «right» and «depth» for nested sets.

I found a similar question here:
[php convert array into a hierarchical nested set for database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31744191/php-convert-array-into-a-hierarchical-nested-set-for-database).

But answer from this branch doesn’t work correctly.

It doesn’t have key «depth» and calculation of keys «left» and «right» is not correct.

**Expected Result:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 27
            [lft] => 1
            [rgt] => 10
            [depth] => 0
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 28
            [lft] => 2
            [rgt] => 3
            [depth] => 1
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 29
            [lft] => 4
            [rgt] => 5
            [depth] => 1
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 30
            [lft] => 6
            [rgt] => 9
            [depth] => 1
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [id] => 31
            [lft] => 7
            [rgt] => 8
            [depth] => 2
        )
)
```

**[id] => 27** - : this is a root node, but I do not show it to users.

Please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: Could you provide the desired output for the example input you give? A bit larger input example would also be helpful.

Comment: The notion of *left* and *right* seems you expect a binary tree as input, but the input example has a root with three elements... that is not binary.

Comment: maybe interesting? [Zebra_Mptt, a PHP class providing an implementation of the modified preorder tree traversal algorithm](http://stefangabos.ro/php-libraries/zebra-mptt). Also, [How do you convert a parent-child (adjacency) table to a nested set using PHP and MySQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4664517/how-do-you-convert-a-parent-child-adjacency-table-to-a-nested-set-using-php-an?rq=1)

Comment: You provided output, but it should be called a miracle if that output is derived from the input. The input has no mention of any of those *url, left* and *right* values you have there in the output. Where do they come from?

Comment: I use: https://github.com/creocoder/yii2-nested-sets

Comment: That does not answer my question.

Comment: Sorry. URL is for convenience (this my correct example in db). We pay attention only to the ID.